# Issue With Padding/Absolutely Positioned Divs

Tags: html, css, padding

I'm having a problem that I've never experienced before. It started happening a few months ago and for the life of me I can't figure out what's going on. I have padding where there should be none and absolutely positioned divs will not position where I tell them to. This is the website:

http://www.underthebelljar.com/

I've put a background color on the areas with issues so you can see what I mean. At the top where it says "Under The Bell Jar", I've got a relative div (the tan) with an absolutely positioned div within it (red) that is positioned to bottom:0;. There is no padding whatsoever on the absolute div but as you can see there's both top and bottom padding unlike the sides that are flush with the div like they should be. I've done this a million times in the past and never had the eensiest problem until it started doing this a few months ago. Same with the main and sidebar areas. The sides are flush with the div but there's padding at the top where I've put no padding.

Thanks for any help you can offer :o)

Comment: did yout try to define a height for #title? i tried height: 25px; on it and the padding disappeared. i hope i didn't misunderstand your problem.

Comment: When I add a height it does diminish the padding but there's still padding and there shouldn't be on the bottom because I've positioned it to bottom:0. I made the #title div 25px and now there's 4px padding above and 2 below.

Comment: Is the problem fixed now? It seems to be just that the font is unusually spaced vertically. As your title is currently positioned, if it contained a g or a q then the tails would not be visible. And changing the font removes the apparent padding.

Comment: I don't see the problem. Could you provide a screenshot?

Comment: I don't see red or tan? Do you still need help?